# TCL how to call item handlers

Tags: tcl

I created the map from the item to item handler.

```
  array set handlers {
             handleItem1 handlerFunction1
             handleItem2 handlerFunction2
  }
```

But handlerFunctions could take parameter.

So below code is not gonna be work.

```
 if { [info exists handlers($item) ] } {
       eval $this $handlers($item)
 }
```

So could I chnage this code to be able to call the handlers which could take the parameters?

Comment: I suggest using command prefixes and invoke them with `{*}`.

Comment: [Johannes Kuhn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn) Could you please show an example, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options:

- **Command prefix** If you are using Tcl 8.5 or later (8.4 is at the end of it's lifetime, upgrade if possible) then the command expansion with `{*}` is the best way to do that.

  ```
  proc putargs args {puts $args}
  set callback {putargs CALLBACK}
  # Invoke it
  {*}$callback param1 param2 ;# prints CALLBACK param1 param2
  ```
- **Script fragment** Eval the callback, but add extra words at the end. (trace does that)

  ```
  proc putargs args {puts $args}
  set callback {putargs CALLBACK [clock seconds]}
  # Invoke
  eval $callback [list param1 param2] ;# Prints CALLBACK 1369834114 param1 param2
  ```

  Allows hacks like `set callback {puts "CALLBACK" ;#}` which will ignore the rest of the line, but it is slower.
- **Command** Not very useful because you can not pass anything.

  ```
  proc putargs args {puts $args}
  set callback {putargs CALLBACK}
  # Invoke
  {*}$callback ;# prints CALLBACK
  ```
- **Script** The parameter are passed as variables in the current scope, sometimes also with string substitution (Tk does that)

  ```
  proc putargs args {puts $args}
  set callback {putargs CALLBACK $param1 $param2}
  # Invoke
  set param1 FOO
  set param2 BAR
  eval $callback ;# prints CALLBACK FOO BAR
  ```
- **Command name** Like the Command prefix, but no expansion is done. (SASL of the Tcllib does that for own mechanisms). Not recommended.

  ```
  proc putargs args {puts $args}
  set callback putargs
  # Invoke
  $callback param1 param2
  ```

The best solution with the best performance is the command prefix.